# Not Able To Login Using SSH Key

Tags: 18.04, server, ssh

I'm having some troubles getting Public Key Authentication working on my server.
I'm currently running Ubuntu 18.04 LTS.

I've got my Public Key added to the authorized_keys file for root but it keeps asking for the password.

So I decided to move into a user on the server, and try to ssh back into the same account to confirm it was all working. Same issue.

The file permissions all look right:

```
dashboard@server:~$ ls -al | grep .ssh
drwx------  2 dashboard dashboard 4096 Feb 24 12:15 .ssh

dashboard@server:~$ ls -al .ssh
total 24
drwx------  2 dashboard dashboard 4096 Feb 24 12:49 .
drwxr-x--- 19 dashboard dashboard 4096 Feb 24 11:33 ..
-rw-rw-r--  1 dashboard dashboard  409 Feb 24 12:49 authorized_keys
-rw-------  1 dashboard dashboard 1675 Feb 24 12:12 id_rsa
-rw-r--r--  1 dashboard dashboard  409 Feb 24 12:12 id_rsa.pub
-rw-r--r--  1 dashboard dashboard  208 Feb 24 12:15 known_hosts
```

After doing some digging around somebody here on the forums had suggested running ssh with -vvv enabled which I've done and have added here. Well, a single -v anyway as with the -vvv option the forums say I am spamming :(

```
dashboard@server:~/.ssh$ ssh -p 8616 dashboard@server.i4z4zi.com -v
OpenSSH_7.6p1 Ubuntu-4ubuntu0.3, OpenSSL 1.0.2n  7 Dec 2017
debug1: Reading configuration data /etc/ssh/ssh_config
debug1: /etc/ssh/ssh_config line 19: Applying options for *
debug1: Connecting to server.i4z4zi.com [95.216.229.124] port 8616.
debug1: Connection established.
debug1: identity file /home/dashboard/.ssh/id_rsa type 0
debug1: key_load_public: No such file or directory
debug1: identity file /home/dashboard/.ssh/id_rsa-cert type -1
debug1: key_load_public: No such file or directory
debug1: identity file /home/dashboard/.ssh/id_dsa type -1
debug1: key_load_public: No such file or directory
debug1: identity file /home/dashboard/.ssh/id_dsa-cert type -1
debug1: key_load_public: No such file or directory
debug1: identity file /home/dashboard/.ssh/id_ecdsa type -1
debug1: key_load_public: No such file or directory
debug1: identity file /home/dashboard/.ssh/id_ecdsa-cert type -1
debug1: key_load_public: No such file or directory
debug1: identity file /home/dashboard/.ssh/id_ed25519 type -1
debug1: key_load_public: No such file or directory
debug1: identity file /home/dashboard/.ssh/id_ed25519-cert type -1
debug1: Local version string SSH-2.0-OpenSSH_7.6p1 Ubuntu-4ubuntu0.3
debug1: Remote protocol version 2.0, remote software version OpenSSH_7.6p1 Ubuntu-4ubuntu0.3
debug1: match: OpenSSH_7.6p1 Ubuntu-4ubuntu0.3 pat OpenSSH* compat 0x04000000
debug1: Authenticating to server.i4z4zi.com:8616 as 'dashboard'
debug1: SSH2_MSG_KEXINIT sent
debug1: SSH2_MSG_KEXINIT received
debug1: kex: algorithm: curve25519-sha256
debug1: kex: host key algorithm: ecdsa-sha2-nistp256
debug1: kex: server->client cipher: chacha20-poly1305@openssh.com MAC: <implicit> compression: none
debug1: kex: client->server cipher: chacha20-poly1305@openssh.com MAC: <implicit> compression: none
debug1: expecting SSH2_MSG_KEX_ECDH_REPLY
debug1: Server host key: ecdsa-sha2-nistp256 SHA256:XfbQEzJnkyHizj6iWI1ckRIKQhfjahFjH5S7EGilTfo
debug1: Host '[server.i4z4zi.com]:8616' is known and matches the ECDSA host key.
debug1: Found key in /home/dashboard/.ssh/known_hosts:1
debug1: rekey after 134217728 blocks
debug1: SSH2_MSG_NEWKEYS sent
debug1: expecting SSH2_MSG_NEWKEYS
debug1: SSH2_MSG_NEWKEYS received
debug1: rekey after 134217728 blocks
debug1: SSH2_MSG_EXT_INFO received
debug1: kex_input_ext_info: server-sig-algs=<ssh-ed25519,ssh-rsa,rsa-sha2-256,rsa-sha2-512,ssh-dss,ecdsa-sha2-nistp256,ecdsa-sha2-nistp384,ecdsa-sha2-nistp521>
debug1: SSH2_MSG_SERVICE_ACCEPT received
debug1: Authentications that can continue: publickey,password
debug1: Next authentication method: publickey
debug1: Offering public key: RSA SHA256:gvwsQMfZdUBiH9ByQZJjwV12zBtc80nS1ahNW7hS6mc /home/dashboard/.ssh/id_rsa
debug1: Authentications that can continue: publickey,password
debug1: Trying private key: /home/dashboard/.ssh/id_dsa
debug1: Trying private key: /home/dashboard/.ssh/id_ecdsa
debug1: Trying private key: /home/dashboard/.ssh/id_ed25519
debug1: Next authentication method: password
```

I would be very grateful if somebody could point me in the right direction as to why it's not working.

The sshd_config file is just the stock standard one that comes with Ubuntu with the exception of me changing the port number and adding UseDNS to no

Cheers,
Craig

Comment: *"I've got my Public Key added to the authorized_keys file for root"* but you are apparently trying to connect as `dashboard@server.i4z4zi.com`, not `root@server.i4z4zi.com` ?

Comment: Yeah my own personal key is added to root's authorized_keys file, but it wasn't working. So I moved to the dashboard user and created a key for dashboard and added it to the authorized_keys file for dashboard to see if I could make it work there.

Answer (score 0):

The contents of the connecting `.ssh/id_rsa.pub` must be in the recievers `.ssh/authorized_keys` or it will never work. Confirm both these and it will work.

```
MacUser2525:~$ cat .ssh/id_rsa.pub 
ssh-rsa AAAAB3NzaC1yc2EAAAABIwAAAQEA
MacUser2525:~$ ssh root@buster-raspi.local
Linux buster-raspi 5.9.0-0.bpo.5-arm64 #1 SMP Debian 5.9.15-1~bpo10+1 (2020-12-31) aarch64

The programs included with the Debian GNU/Linux   system are free software;
the exact distribution terms for each program are    described in the
individual files in /usr/share/doc/*/copyright.

Debian GNU/Linux comes with ABSOLUTELY NO WARRANTY, to the extent
permitted by applicable law.
Last login: Fri Feb  5 18:36:56 2021
root@buster-raspi:~# cat .ssh/authorized_keys 
ssh-rsa AAAAB3NzaC1yc2EAAAABIwAAAQE
root@buster-raspi:~# cat /etc/ssh/sshd_config | grep Root
#PermitRootLogin prohibit-password
# the setting of "PermitRootLogin without-password".
root@buster-raspi:~# cat /etc/ssh/sshd_config | grep root
#ChrootDirectory none
```

Now I see the security through obscurity yet again with that port used. If this machine is outside of the local network trying this port moving technique for security is useless. The machines that scan the internet looking for open ports do not care if you have changed it. They go through every port in existence on every IP in existence, god only knows how many times a day. They will find your service with its changed listening port without any trouble at all. Or do you think they do not know there are other ports these services can run on?  They are that stupid, right. My pasted blurb for just this circumstance.

Comment: Can confirm both the .ssh/authorized_keys file and the id_rsa.pub keys match 100% - and no I'm not so stupid as to think that moving the port is going to magically solve all issues but the truth is we see fewer hits on a different port rather than the default port 22 *shrugs*

Comment: Fewer is not none, I stand by the statement. Though only some of them are not that stupid, taking into account your experience. No clue then it works without fail when I do it, I fail to see how it would be different for you. Only difference is mine being done without a single edit to the configuration. Simple logic tells you it is something in those edits that does it.